# how to sort by date (new) with jquery isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Forgive me as I'm a bit novice to JS, just know enough to manipulate.

For those familiar with Isotope ( http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html ), I have a button at the top of a page to sort by date. Isotope finds the element

```
<span class="date"> 01/04/2012 </span>
```

with this:

```
$container.isotope({
    getSortData : {
        date : function ( $elem ) {
        return $elem.find('.date').text();
}});
```

Which works fine, but I need to flip (descend) the date order

Isotope has a function:

```
$('#container').isotope({ 
  sortBy : 'date',
  sortAscending : false
});
```

But I can't get it to work - that just makes the default set sort by date, rather than sorting when I click. I think this is just a question of syntax... how/where can I put sortAscending: false  ??

Thanks...

**EDIT Viewing some source from Demos, I see that:**

```
<a href="#sortAscending=false">
```

Can be done, but I'm already sorting by passing this:

```
<a href="#sortBy=date">
```

Which finds a the span from earlier with the date info...

Comment: Not to resurrect an old thread, but did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I did it, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Y4mUN/12/)

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element',
    getSortData: {
        date: function ($elem) {
            return Date.parse($elem.find('.date').text());
        }
    }
});
```

It doesn't seem to matter what format the date is in, and works ascending and descending.

The parse() method parses a date string and returns the number of milliseconds between the date string and midnight of January 1, 1970.

Basically it turns your date strings into nice solid numbers which are easy to compare.

Comment: Thank you! that jsFiddle has a lot sorting examples!

Comment: I have played with your jsFiddle, and it does not seem to actually work. Try turning off the variable sizing first, so you can see the sort order better.

Comment: @magi182 did you click the date button?

Comment: I did that. I was trying to see how your sort order worked, and it seems a little off...   Here's what I did: 1. click "Toggle variable sizes" so it is easier to see the sort order. 2. click "date" under Sort tabs. 3. try to click sort ascending or sort descending expecting it to reverse the sort order... it doesn't seem to sort properly...

Comment: @magi182 I just checked it again and it seems to be working properly. I even added more dates to test with. Checked ascending and descending as well... Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 4):

Heres what I did to sort by date.

If your date is in the format of '01/01/2012' then you need to convert it to a javascript date object.

```
getSortData: {
    date: function ($elem) {
        var dateStr = $elem.find('.date').text(),
            dateArray = dateStr.split('/'),
            year = dateArray[2],
            month = dateArray[0],
            day = dateArray[1];
        return new Date(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

then you do your usual

```
$('#container').isotope({ sortBy: 'date' });
```

Comment: You should return this "return year.toString() + month.toString() + day.toString();" that, your return will sort days of the week alphabetically