# jQuery: isotope sorting by unix datestamp

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to sort an isotope grid by date, each grid item being a wordpress post, thus the unix date stamp is called like so `<?php echo strtotime(get_the_time()); ?>`.
Which re-produces in the front end (in date order, from most recent downwards)—
Post 1: `1374656580`
Post 2: `1374654540`
Post 3: `1374651000`
Post 4: `1374661200`
Post 5: `1374676560`
Post 6: `1374676020`
Which doesn't work when sorting in either ascending or descending order, is there a friendlier date format that will allow to be sorted in descending order via the isotope sort method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795247/how-to-sort-by-date-new-with-jquery-isotope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it should work. Do you know if the timestamps are numeric or string? Maybe if you would convert them to string (I would also 0-pad it)
"0001374656580"
"0001374654540"
etc