# Sort by date using Isotope, breaking down into day/months/years

Tags: php, sorting, date, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope to arrange and sort a bunch of elements. I have buttons controlling all the sorting.

I can't get the 'date' sorting to work properly. I have the date being printed inside each element to be sorted and applied a class of .date to it. it currently prints as dd/mm/yy

```
<span class="date"><?php the_date('d/m/y');?></span>
```

In its simplest form I can sort using -

```
getSortData: {
  date: '.date',
}
```

This will organise into number order which is fine for the days but then goes wrong when it comes to months. How can I get the sort to sort by a true date rather than just a number.

I have tried using the examples I've found already on Stackoverflow but each one breaks the isotope completely and the elements do not even layout. Below is an example of another sort I have that does work, maybe someone can use this to see what I need to do?

```
distance: function( itemElem ) {
var distance= $( itemElem ).find('.wppl-address').text();
return parseFloat( distance.replace( /[\(\)]/g, '') );
  },
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to sort by date (new) with jquery isotope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795247/how-to-sort-by-date-new-with-jquery-isotope)

Comment: I've just updated my question. The examples given 'break' isotope for me so I've included another sort I'm using that does work to see if that helps...

Comment: You need to convert dates to proper date objects in js, which can then be sorted by the true date chronological, while displaying the date in whatever format you have it in.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example Anthony? I'm quite new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Have php output :

```
 <span class="date" 
   data-date="<?php the_date('c');?>" >
 <?php the_date('d/m/y');?>
 </span>
```

Then use :

```
 getSortData: {
      date: function($item) {
            return $item.data('date');
        }
 }
```

Or try out:

```
 getSortData: {
      date: function($item) {
            return new Date($item.data('date'));
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm already using name: as a sort to get alphabetical order. is there a way to change what you've provided to avoid  clash?

Comment: Hi Anthony. Clicking the sort button does nothing. I assume I'd need to change this to match your code somehow? <button class="button" data-sort-by="date">Date Added</button>

Comment: The documentation is very misleading. try the updated `date` as function.